# Different strange behaviour withUIPickerView selectedRowInComponent in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, sms, uipickerview

I have a strange thing happening with my app now after iOS5 updates.

I have a UIPickerView and use `[customPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]` to get the picked component. The user picks the second row (with index 1)

So it looks like:

```
i = [customPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];   // -> i is 1 here, is OK!
[smsAgent  sendSMS:smsTxt]; //just call another method to send a SMS
```

The value of `i` is OK when checking.
Now I just call a the normal SMS dialogue `smsAgent` which looks essentially like this:

```
smsAgent...
      MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
      picker.messageComposeDelegate = delegate;
      picker.recipients =[NSArray arrayWithObject: myTelNumber];  
      [delegate presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

certainly not doing anything to my picker.

But when this "returns" in

```
    - (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //take away the SMS screen fast, so we can send selectModeVCDidFinish to take away ourselves
        int j = [customPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
        [self.delegate selectModeVCDidFinish: selectedMode];
}
```

the value **j is 0 again, not 1**!

For sure nothing happens to the customPickerView - I am really puzzled - what's going on here?

Before updating to iOS5 there was no problem whatsoever.

Is there something that I missed?

Many thanks

Comment: Are these calls all in the same object? The "delegate" that you set for the compose controller is the view controller that owns the pocket view? My guess is that in your last code segment, the customPickerView is actually nil.

Comment: no - that's not it, the UIPickerView is in object A only which calls the smsAgent object providing itself as the delegate. So smsAgent returns back to object A, which holds the UIPickerView. But after the return the picked value is not correct again...

Comment: Since `i` looks like an ivar, why not just set `j = i`?

Comment: Yes, I will do this - however why doesn't selectedRowInComponent work correctly anymore?

Comment: When you dismiss the message compose view controller and the picker controller is showed again, is the row still selected ? Maybe you lost the selection when you show another view controller in front of your picker controller

Comment: for anybody who may experience something similar - check the order of callbacks. While in the previous iOS versions the callback of the MFMessageComposeViewController was faster than the showing the screen, in iOS5 its the other way around. That causes some strange behaviour...

Comment: Hi user387184, I'm facing a similar issue with my picker control. I've my code based on [CustomPickerView](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/longer-spinning-blurring-v20.html) and these have stopped spinning ever since I've migrated to 5.0. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: check the order of messages that are called - this was the problem in my case. - it changed somewhat in iOS5

Comment: @the.evangelist do you still have the same problem? because this is an old question but you opened a bounty...

Comment: @Luis - yes the reason for opening bounty was to encourage people to look and solve the issue I was facing for UIPickerView (please look into my comment and link above). After lot of exploration realized the problem was that "scrollAnimationDuration" is not available anymore from 5.0 onwards. But thanks for looking into my question and your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for explaining the problem in detail. I had a problem with my UIPickerViews. As mentioned in my comment above, my code was based on CustomPickerView - http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/longer-spinning-blurring-v20.html

This code fell apart from version 5.0. After doing a lot of research I found that it was not the problem with the sequence/order of delegate functions being called for UIPicker.

But the unofficial function "scrollAnimationDuration" in particular has been deprecated and not available for use. This was the reason for UIPicker not scrolling for longer duration (as it did for iOS 4.3.3 and below).

Answer (score -1):

As I have written in my comment, the reason for this behaviour is the order in which the methods get called. Let me explain in detail:

The starting screen screenVC has the normal methods viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. Within these messages the picker gets created (or whatever element) and is set to the value that is provided by the underlying data structures. SO lets say the picker gets 10.

Now when choosing a different value 20 that's put in a variable and I thought this would be SAVE.

Now the SMS dialog opens and one sends the sms.

But what happens now is the reason for this strange problem. When the SMS dialog disappears the screenVC fires viewWillAppear, this sets the variable BACK to 10 (since the data structures have not been updated yet)

Now the sms comes back into didFinishWithResult and the underlying 20 is lost.

So all you need to do is to ensure that the variable used to update your data structure from within sms didFinishWithResult is passed as a parameter with your dismiss call of the screen.

Just an additional issue. Even more surprising if screenVC opens another screen2VC which only has the picker (and sets the value to 10) and this one then opens the sms dialog. When the sms dialog returns it causes screen2VC to call viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear even though they were dismissed.

I suppose this happens because the sms dialog starter screen needs to be there when the sms dialog dismisses.

Hopefully I could explain well enough to understand - just ask if its not clear.

And as a last comment: put debug statements into the code where your variable in question is beeing assigned - there you can see that the assignemnt is being called even though you did not expect/think of it.

Comment: Dear downvoter - "thank you very much" for your downvote. All I did was spent extra time to explain the issue I discovered in detail to help - if this did not turn out to be the same as in your case then go on and downvote....

Comment: Dear user387184, thanks for spending time to explain the issue. But  looks like you did not look into my previous comment for your original post and understand the reason for "bounty", which is unfortunate. The problem you explained was with ordering for viewWillAppear/viewDidLoad - it nowhere got closer to UIPicker problem (Which was the core for this issue). Hence I'd to downvote your answer. But many thanks for your time explaining the flow.